How do you take apart the 4.5V Right Switch Track with White Ties?
I have part x879cx1, and its centrepiece that moves back and forth is broken (the lever snapped off, and a bit of the track on its lefthand side). Luckily I bought a bulk lot which had a loose one of these, so I want to replace it. I don't see how to safely take it out though: I assume you're meant to move it downwards since the base of the main piece has a lip that goes over the base of the centrepiece, and, looking at the loose centre piece I have, it has a little nib at the top (which sits under the main piece), so you can't take it out parallel to the main piece. I tried pulling the centre piece out downwards, but I'm scared of breaking the main piece so I didn't pull very hard (I don't know where to put my fingers when trying, since I don't want to put pressure on the tracks of the main piece).


Also, the white part doesn't seem to be separable from the blue tracks, so I don't think I can get the centre piece out that way:


Edit:
This is a photo of the stationary part found online, showing the connection points:


I don't have such a piece, but I'd try removing the white piece first, then applying pressure from above on the round "top" part of the middle element, where the nib is holding on to the main piece. After that is clear, try pulling the middle piece "down" as per your photo to clear the lower lip.

@zovits Unfortunately the white part seems to be moulded with the blue part: I can see a bit of blue colour on the edge of the white part so they don't look like separate bricks.

That's definitely curious, can you please take a close-up photo of the interface between the blue and white parts? As far as I knew, LEGO didn't manufacture overmolded pieces before 2009

I have a feeling that it's glued rather than moulded together.

@zovits Added two images to the question for you :) The blue part leaking into the white part appears 6 times on one side, and not at all on the other. I didn't notice it before, but the studs of the white part do appear under the tracks when they don't need to.

Thanks for the photos. It seems you're right in that these parts can't be separated easily, because they have been glued together using acetone, which melts the ABS. That process produces such drop-like marks at the interface. Since the broken piece needs to be able to move, it must not be glued there - might the white piece flex enough to allow for the removal of the nib of the middle element?
